# Fortran Fallback code for optional string argument

Tags: string, fortran, optional-parameters

So I'd like to pass an optional string to a subroutine, that if the string doesn't exist set a fallback string. However i don't want to set the length of the fallback string at compile time. So i've had two ideas for sorting this out doStufFirst and doStuffSecond

So i have this:

```
MODULE stuff
    implicit none

    contains

subroutine dostuffFirst (string)
   implicit none
   character(len=*),intent(in),optional :: string
   character(len=min(8,len(string))) :: outString

   if(present(string)) THEN
    outString=string
   else
     outString="fallBack"
   endif

  call doStuff2(outString)

 end subroutine dostuffFirst


subroutine dostuffSecond (string)
    implicit none
    character(len=*),optional :: string
    character,dimension(:),allocatable :: outString
    integer :: i

   if(present(string)) THEN
    ALLOCATE(outString(len(string)))
        do i=1,len(string)
          outString(i)=string(i:i)
        end do
    else
        ALLOCATE(outString(8))
        outString(1:8)=(/"f","a","l","l","B","a","c","k"/)
    endif

    call doStuff2(outString)

end subroutine dostuffSecond


      subroutine doStuff2(str)
       implicit none
       character(len=*),intent(in) :: str

       write(*,*) str

      end subroutine doStuff2

end module stuff

PROGRAM prog
     use stuff
     implicit none


      call dostuffFirst("123")

      call dostuffSecond("123")

END program prog
```

But the problem with doStuffFirst is that i can't have the len(string) of an optional argument in the declaration of outString. And the problem with dostuffSecond is i've now made a rank-1 array but doStuff2 is expecting a scalar (and would be infeasible to change everything afterwards to expect an array)

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: If one isn't restricted to (the very very old) Fortran 90 standard, then deferred length character variables are worth considering.  Along with a [tag:fortran] retag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the problem in `dostuffFirst`, trying to establish the length of the character variable to pass to `doStuff2` could you do the `PRESENT` logic in `doStuff2` itself?

```
subroutine doStuff2(str)
  character(len=*), intent(in), optional :: str

  if (PRESENT(str)) then
    write(*,*) str
  else
    write(*,*) "fallback"
  end if
emd subroutine doStuff2
```

I'll admit this latter can get a bit cumbersome if going on more than once, but one can indeed use wrappers as with your `dostuffFirst` attempt.  One way, if you don't need a variable which takes either the input string or the fallback string is as follows.

```
subroutine dostuffFirst (string)
   character(len=*),intent(in),optional :: string

   if(present(string)) THEN
     call doStuff2(string)
   else
     call doStuff2("fallBack")
   endif

 end subroutine dostuffFirst
```

Of course, if you have a lot of possible strings, this also gets very awkward very quickly (lots of nested `if`s).

```
subroutine dostuffFirst(string1, string2, string3)
  character(len=*), intent(in), optional :: string1, string2, string3

  if (PRESENT(string1)) then
    if (PRESENT(string2)) then
      if (PRESENT(string3)) then
        call doStuff2(string1, string2, string3)
      else
        call doStuff2(string1, string2, "fallback3")
  ! etc
end subroutine dostuffFirst
```

The traditional way to get around these things is choosing a massively long `str_to_use`s.

```
subroutine dostuffFirst(string1, string2, string3)
  character(len=*), intent(in), optional :: string1, string2, string3
  character(AS_LONG_AS_I_EVER_NEED) str_to_use1, str_to_use2, str_to_use3

  if (PRESENT(string1)) then
    str_to_use1 = string1
  else
    str_to_use1 = "fallback1"
  end if
  ! etc
  call doStuff2(str_to_use1, str_to_use2, str_to_use3)
end subroutine dostuffFirst
```

However, if you are happy to move to a more modern compiler/coding standard, then you have the luxury of deferred length character variables.

```
subroutine dostuffFirst(string1, string2, string3)
  character(len=*), intent(in), optional :: string1, string2, string3
! Deferred length working variables
  character(:), allocatable :: str_to_use1, str_to_use2, str_to_use3

  if (PRESENT(string1)) then
    str_to_use1 = string1
  else
    str_to_use1 = "fallback1"
  end if
  ! etc
  call doStuff2(str_to_use1, str_to_use2, str_to_use3)
end subroutine dostuffFirst
```

Which is much the same as the previous case, but without the worry of the correct choice of length.

Comment: Thanks, the idea behind this was that there would be 1 function that dealt with this optional/default stuff then all functions afterwards only have to worry about accepting a string. Never new you could do a character(len=:), allocatable always assumed you needed dimension/pointer to allocate

Comment: I've revised the answer based on your comment.  Note that `character(len=:), allocatable` is a Fortran 2003 feature.  I've avoided retagging your question with the more generic Fortran tag (but would recommend you do unless you really do require a strict Fortran 90 answer) as it seems cheeky to do so to fit my answer.