# Fortran Optional Arguments

Tags: fortran

I am writing a routine to write strings. Would I need to
check which arguments are present, or can I avoid that?

```
Subroutine writes  & 
(                  &
 q1, q2, q3, q4    & 
)

Character (len=*), Intent(in) :: q1
Character (len=*), Intent(in), Optional :: q2, q3, q4

Character (len=65) :: s, fmt

fmt = "(x,4(a,x))"
Write (s,fmt) Trim (q1), Trim (q2), Trim (q3), Trim (q4)
Write (*,*) Trim (s)

End Subroutine writes
```

Comment: To guide an answer, why do you think one can avoid checking presence at some point?  Although `trim` doesn't take optional arguments, one can do wrapping much as in a [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27343054/3157076).

Comment: Not sure that  a wrapper is going to help. Because if I define a new function, the size of the returned character string has to be fixed.

Comment: `character(len=:), allocatable :: result`?

Comment: Also, in this implementation, if called as `writes('a',q4='b')` the output will be `a   b` (extra spaces).  Is this what is wanted?

Comment: One sends a list of strings and are printed with a space between them. Have not ever tried using `character(len=:), allocatable :: result`

Comment: Now would the allocatation of the result be as `Allocate (result (Len_trim(input)) )`

Comment: No, `allocate(character(whatever) :: result)`

Comment: To some extent https://stackoverflow.com/q/25390942 would be worth a read.

Answer (score 4):

The rules regarding use of optional dummy arguments are given, clearly, in Fortran 2008 12.5.2.12.  If all arguments are present in the call to `writes` as given in the question then the code is valid and the output would be as expected.  However, one can't guarantee this and any non-present argument would make the code invalid.

In particular, passing `q2`, say, which is not present to `TRIM` (which doesn't take an optional argument) would be wrong.

There are multiple ways of addressing this problem, but they all involve checking presence.  You could follow the arguments in [Fortran Fallback code for optional string argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25390942), but below is an alternative as given previously in comments.

It is possible to create an alternative to `TRIM` which does take an optional argument, returning a zero-length character variable if the argument is not present, and the expected trimmed variable if it is:

```
  subroutine writes(q1, q2, q3, q4)
    character(*), intent(in) :: q1, q2, q3, q4
    optional q2, q3, q4
    character(len=65) s

    write(s, '(4(a,:,x))') TRIM(q1), MY_TRIM(q2), MY_TRIM(q3), MY_TRIM(q4)
    print*, TRIM(s)

  contains
    function my_trim(str)
      character(*), intent(in), optional :: str
      character(:), allocatable :: my_trim

      if (PRESENT(str)) then
        my_trim = TRIM(str)
      else
        my_trim = ''
      end if

    end function

  end subroutine
```

Note, this uses a deferred length character variable for the result, along with automatic allocation (if using ifort remember the necessary compiler flags to correctly compile).

Finally, if you want to ensure that spaces aren't printed between two non-present variables (`''//' '//''`) extra work will be required.  However, the comments indicate that this isn't necessary.

Comment: I do not need to call `allocate` on `my_trim` in the function, then. I thought I had to.

Comment: You do not need to, but if you want to (for clarity, to avoid automatic allocation, etc.) then you'll have to use the form given by Vladimir F in comments above.  Separate allocations for each case.